Issue with Retrieving Token from Keychain After Hard Reboot on Apple TV
In our application, we store user information (Username, Password, AccessToken, Refresh token, etc.) in the keychain. However, after performing a hard reboot (unplugging and plugging back in), when we attempt to retrieve the ‘refresh token’ or ‘access token’ from the keychain, we receive the old token instead of the newly saved one.
Scenario:

User logged in and received a token N.
We save it in keychain (Save N).
We fetch it from  keychain just to verify if it was saved - (we get N)
Reboot the Apple TV and the refresh call is being made with token N - 1 (previously saved token in the keychain).

I expected to retrieve the latest ‘refresh token’ or ‘access token’ from the keychain after a hard reboot.
